# Creating and managing database in Godaddy server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, webserver

I want to create and manage a database in my Godaddy server for authentication purpose. How can i do this?..Is there any pre-configuration needs to be done in the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends of your server os, but there's a guide for setting up a mysql server

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/installing.html

for pre-configuration look at [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) and leave port 3306 open for mysql